# Zipping files x days old into folder per day

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to go through a folder and Zip up any files modified that are 30 days old and zip them into a file with name MM/dd/yyyy.

I've been trying to use this

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 30; $i++) 
{
$Date = get-date -format d((get-date).adddays(-$i))
get-childitem "\\Directory\*" | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -eq $date}
}
```

But using this only gets the date time 00:00 and nothing was created or modified at that time. I need to to check for anything created that day entirely.

How can I get this to return anything created or modified anytime that day instead of a specific time?

I will use this to zip the files into a folder but this is not where I am stuck.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Dir, $DirZip)
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the equals comparison it is strictly looking for an exact match.  Instead you should check for a range of days, you can do this using greater-than and less-than.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\Directory\*" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$i) -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$i+1) }
```

Comment: If I did it this way it returns everything less than 30 days old and I wouldn't be able to zip them into separate folders based on day. That's why i'm using the for loop so that it will return every file in the directory that is 1 day old, and then it would zip it to a folder with that date and go onto 2 days old and so forth until 30 days old.

Thanks

Comment: OK, in that case you just want to specify a range (using gt/lt) instead of eq.  I will update my example in the answer.